# setjmp remarks defined by standard

Tags: c

**ISO/IEC 9899:1999**

> **7.13.1.1 The setjmp macro**
>
> Environmental limits 4 An invocation of the setjmp macro shall appear
>   only in one of the following contexts: — the entire controlling
>   expression of a selection or iteration statement; — one operand of a
>   relational or equality operator with the other operand an integer
>   constant expression, with the resulting expression being the entire
>   controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; — the
>   operand of a unary ! operator with the resulting expression being the
>   entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;
>   or — the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast
>   to void).

So, the only variants of using setjmp are the following:

```
if (setjmp(buf))
while (setjmp(buf))
for (;; setjmp(buf))

if (setjmp(buf) == 0)
while (setjmp(buf) == 0)
for (;; setjmp(buf) == 0)

if (!setjmp(buf))
while (!setjmp(buf))
for (;; !setjmp(buf))

setjmp(buf);
(void)setjmp(buf);
```

And we can't use this statements:

```
int foo = setjmp(buf);
foo = setjmp(buf);
```

Right? What they mean by the iteration statement? The last statement of the for loop?

Comment: I think you got the controlling expression of the `for` statement wrong. It is the middle one.

Comment: The last two statements with ``foo = setjmp(buf)`` are okay due to this: "or — the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void)"

Comment: @jszakmeister: No, an expression statement your garden-variety statement `expr;`.  `foo = setjmp(buf);` is an expression statement, but the `setjmp` call is *not* the **entire** expression statement, it is just the RHS of the assignment.  That subclause allows the statements `setjmp(buf);` and `(void)setjmp(buf);` but nothing else.

Comment: Doh!  You're right @AdamRosenfield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't use

```
int foo = setjmp(buf);
foo = setjmp(buf);
```

The reason for the later (assignment) is probably that an assignment is an expression, that can have more than just an identifier on the left side. If the left side is an lvalue expression the standard imposes no order in which the subexpressions are evalutated. So if you have

```
int* f(void);
*f() = setjmp(buf);
```

`*f()` and `setjmp(buf)` could be evaluated in any order. Since `setjmp` makes a snapshot of the actual state of the abstract state machine, the semantics of boths orders would be completely different.

For the first line (initialization) this problem doesn't occur, I think. So I guess this could be added as a valid use. But it would have to be discussed carefully if there are no border cases that still require an evaluation on the left side.

(Eric already replied for the selection statements.)

Answer (score 2):

Selection statements are `if` (including `if…else`) and `switch`. Iteration statements are `while`, `do…while`, and `for`.

Comment: And more specifically, the *controlling expression* of an iteration statement is the predicate which determines whether or not it will loop: the argument of `while` or the middle argument of `for`.

Comment: So this two statements will not working? int foo = setjmp(buf);
foo = setjmp(buf);

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: The language of the C standard means that the C standard does not **require** setjmp to work when you use it in assignments like that. It might or might not work, depending on your C implementation. Therefore, you **cannot rely** on it unless your C implementation’s documentation contains guarantees beyond what the C standard requires.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `switch`, the **only** way to make any practical use of the argument to `longjmp`.