# C: Passing Strings by reference?

Tags: c, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, setjmp

I wrote the following code in order to understand setjmp and longjmp functions but I think the issue is unrelated to those functions. I am expecting the output to be:

```
function1
function2
function2
```

but I keep getting:

```
function1
function2
function1
```

as the out put. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f1(char * a);
void f2(char * a);

jmp_buf buf1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char * w;
   f1( w);
   return 0;
}

void f1(char * a)
{
   a = "funtion 1";
   printf("%s\n",a);

   int i = setjmp( buf1 );
   if( i == 0 )
      f2( a );

   printf("%s\n", a);

}

void f2(char * a)
{
   a = "function 2";
   printf("%s\n",a);
   longjmp( buf1 , 2 );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you did wrong was to overwrite `char *a`.

Comment: `int i = setjmp( buf1 );` you cannot use the "return value" from setjmp() in an assignment (in this case the initialiser is an assignment), only to test it in a if or switch condition (maybe even while/do/for)

Comment: See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/12204143/2235885

Answer (score 3):

There is no pass by reference in [c](/questions/tagged/c) it's only pass by value. However, you can pass a pointer to the pointer in `main()`, like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *w;
   f1(&w);
   return 0;
}

void f1(char **a)
{
   *a = "funtion 1";
   printf("%s\n", *a);

   int i = setjmp( buf1 );
   if (i == 0)
      f2(a);
   printf("%s\n", *a);

}

void f2(char **a)
{
   *a = "function 2";
   printf("%s\n", *a);
   longjmp(buf1 , 2);
}
```

**NOTE**:  Be very careful with this, you are assigning a string literal and you shall not attempt to modify it.

Comment: I had to remove the '&' in the 'f2(&a)' for this to work. Any reason why that might be ?

Comment: Yes, it should be like that. Sorry, it's my mistake